# Replace the content of all cells matching a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I loop through an entire dataframe to remove data in cells that contain a particular string when the column names are unknown?

Here’s what I have so far:

```
for (i in colnames(df)){
   df2 = df[~df[i].str.contains('found')]
```

My data:

```
  Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/ Getting links from: https://www.boo.com/ Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/
0           ├───OK─── http://www.this.com/           ├───OK─── http://www.this.com/           ├───OK─── http://www.this.com/
1             ├───OK─── http://www.is.com/             ├───OK─── http://www.is.com/             ├───OK─── http://www.is.com/
2         ├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/     2 links found. 0 excluded. 0 broken.         ├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/
3                                      NaN                                      NaN            ├───OK─── http://www.set.com/
4                                      NaN                                      NaN            ├───OK─── http://www.one.com/
```

How can I delete the entire contents of a cell if it contains a string, for instance, 'found'? I want to delete everything in the cell (including before and after the string.)

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding _delete the entire contents_ , do you want it to contain a None NaN or perhaps an empty string ?

Comment: An empty string is the intended result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) here:

```
import re    

# just make sure all values are string type
df = df.astype(str)    

# remove the text which has word found
df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub('.*found.*','',x ))

                                          0
0  Getting links from: https://www.boo.com/
1            ├───OK─── http://www.this.com/
2              ├───OK─── http://www.is.com/
3                                          
4                                       nan
5                                       nan
```

Comment: this is crisp. :) +1

Comment: @YOLO thank you for the suggestion! I'm getting an error: "TypeError: ('expected string or buffer', u'occured at index Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/') Any insight?

Comment: @lane how does the header look like? is that the header ?

Comment: @lane when you read the data, make sure you do `header=None`, i edited a bit in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking for a string/value to check and take the action against the whole DataFrame hence `DataFrame.replace` method fits the caveats here ..

**Example DataFrame:**

```
>>> df
      a
0  foo1
1  foo2
2   bar
3   bar
4   bar
```

Replacing `bar` with blank or you can replace it with `NaN` Value if desired:

```
>>> df.replace("bar", "", regex=True)
      a
0  foo1
1  foo2
2
3
4
```

Or replace `bar` with `NaN`

```
>>> df.replace("bar", np.nan, regex=True)
 # df.replace("bar", np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
      a
0  foo1
1  foo2
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
```

You can choose to have `inplace=True` if you like to replace to take place into the actual dataframe:

**Simulated the example as given:**

```
>>> df
                                                                                                                         col1
0  Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/ Getting links from: https://www.boo.com/ Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/
1            ├───OK─── http://www.this.com/           ├───OK─── http://www.this.com/           ├───OK─── http://www.this.com/
2              ├───OK─── http://www.is.com/             ├───OK─── http://www.is.com/             ├───OK─── http://www.is.com/
3          ├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/     2 links found. 0 excluded. 0 broken.         ├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/
4                                       NaN                                      NaN            ├───OK─── http://www.set.com/
5                                       NaN                                      NaN            ├───OK─── http://www.one.com/
```

Result with str.contains:

```
>>> df[~df["col1"].str.contains("found")]
                                                                                                                         col1
0  Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/ Getting links from: https://www.boo.com/ Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/
1            ├───OK─── http://www.this.com/           ├───OK─── http://www.this.com/           ├───OK─── http://www.this.com/
2              ├───OK─── http://www.is.com/             ├───OK─── http://www.is.com/             ├───OK─── http://www.is.com/
4                                       NaN                                      NaN            ├───OK─── http://www.set.com/
5                                       NaN                                      NaN            ├───OK─── http://www.one.com/
```

OR as Stated make sure values are string type to apply the operation

```
>>> df[~df["col1"].astype(str).str.contains("found")]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! After running that line, the data is unchanged. I added my data to my post for you to look at.

Comment: As the documentation states it's using `re.sub` under the hood, yet in a more convenient interface in my opinion. @lane have you added `inplace=True` ? or  `df = df.replace("bar", "", regex=True)`

Comment: @Oleg yes, I've tried both. No errors, but also no change.

Comment: Also, I think the string should be replaced with the regex as mentioned in @YOLO's answer `.*found.*` in order to replace the entire str and not just the exact part that matched

Comment: Sorry, was awy from the system, @Oleg rightly said replace method i placed in my answer before the post was re-updated, However,  Yolo's answer should do the Job for the updated post.

Comment: Even `df[~df["col1"].str.contains("found")]` is working fine for me .

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with nan with df.replace({'test':np.nan}) and that should replace all instances